# How to display pdf in browser from database using Xamarin and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, model-view-controller, xamarin.forms

I have a listview in Xamarin form, which you can see in the screenshot here:

[ListView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gTv6.png)

and this is my database structure

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GHFc.png)

as you can see in database i have file content which is in binary format and these binary data are pdf files, i need to display these pdf in browser.

In my listview, I am retrieving data with button, what i want is  when the user clicks on button, a PDF file should open in browser from the database based on id.

This is my xaml code

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="12,6">
                <Label Text="{Binding ReportName}" 
                       FontSize="24" 
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                <Label Text="{Binding Date}"  
                       FontSize="18" 
                       Opacity="0.6"
                       Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"/>
                  <Button Clicked="ShowPDF" Text="View" CommandParameter="{Binding FileContent}"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>

protected void ShowPDF(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

            Button button = (Button)sender;

            string path = button.CommandParameter.ToString();



            Navigation.PushAsync(new PDFView(path));
        }
```

Comment: what have you done so far upload your code

Comment: So far what i have done this is my code but its not working and i know i am doing wrong 
`<Button Clicked="ShowPDF" Text="View" CommandParameter="{Binding FileContent}"></Button>
 protected void ShowPDF(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            string path = button.CommandParameter.ToString();
            Navigation.PushAsync(new PDFView(path));
        }`

Comment: any help with this problem?

Comment: Please update your answer this way its hard to understand

Comment: i have updated my answer, but i know i am doing it shouldnt work like this as i have binary data in database and need to display in browser so this code is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

Well usually when I have to show a pdf file using xamarin forms I use a WebView the best example I can provide you with is [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/display-pdf/)

Also, I recently saw this working example on [github](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/Controls/DisplayPDF/)

Goodluck!

In case you face problems revert back!

Comment: well github page not working, and the problem i am facing that i have binary data in my database for pdf, how i can view that data in webview?

Comment: Check the first link out it has the steps!

Comment: i have  checked that link not helpful because it shows how to display pdf from local path as for my case i dont have pdf in my pc as well its on database as binary data

Comment: then what you can do is get it from the database convert it to pdf save it and then display that is what all apps do usually i thought you might have known that